# Where and how is stored the information about "System boot has changed" when C: is BitLocker-encrypted?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, encryption, bitlocker

To understand more precisely how things are handled, when BitLocker is enabled for C:\ , how does Windows know that:

- normally, it should start **without any key prompt**
- if something changes in BIOS config, **it should ask** for the BitLocker recovery key
- if I take the HDD out of this computer, and put it in another computer, **it should ask** for the BitLocker recovery key

?

I can imagine something like that: a *cryptographic hash* `h1` of the current BIOS config state can be computed and stored (where?). Then Windows also stores a copy of this hash `h2` in a file on the volume C:\ itself or in the boot partition (where?). On each boot, if `h1 == h2` no password is asked to the user. If `h1 != h2`, this means that the BIOS has changed or the disk has been moved to another computer, and therefore the recovery key is asked.

Is this more or less correct?

More precisely what system handles these things, and where are these "hash" stored?

Is it [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) or something else? If so, where is stored this information?

Answer (score 1):

If available (and suitable) Bitlocker uses the TPM module of your computer to store the cryptographic hash values.

Or to be precise Bitlocker/Windows needs to provide the correct hash values to the TPM to unseal it and allow to decrypt the key used by Bitlocker.

If one of the hash values is different e.g. because of a change in the BIOS firmware or setting the TPM can not be unsealed and Bitlocker can't boot. In such a case usually Bitlocker asks for a recovery key to be entered.

For details see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/tpm-fundamentals

Comment: It would be useful to add https://github.com/mattifestation/TCGLogTools as a way to read the (in-memory) event log which shows how each PCR's hash chain is computed.